# jQUery Mobile - how can I pass back values on dialog close?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a form page that opens a dialog in order to enter new information. I open the dialog in the "standard" jQM way:

```
<a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

What I need to do is pass back some of the values that were entered so that I can update the page with those values. How do I do that?

As an added bonus, I also really need to be able to submit the values. It seems like jQuery Mobile is setup close the page on any link click. This is an ASP.NET application, and so I need for the page to last long enough to hit the Button_Click() event in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pieces you need:

Html in the dialog:

```
<a href="#"data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
<a href="#" id="btnSave" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transition="pop">Submit</a>
```

In pagecreate:

```
$("#btnSave", pagediv).live('click', function () {
        var s = page.Model;
        s.serverName = $("#txtName", pagediv).val();
        s.Save(function () {
            $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
        });
    });
```

s.Save is a function that writes to the datastore, updates a global model object that is accessible to all pages, then calls the callback function.

In the pageshow handler for the parent page, update the controls from the model. You can't update the parent page directly from the dialog as the parent page may not exist at that point - if data-dom-cache isn't set, it will be removed as soon as the dialog is displayed and will not be recreated until you call close.